# Getting Random Forest feature_importances_ from OneVsRestClassifier for Multi-label classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am using OneVsRestClassifier for a multi-label classification problem. I am passing RandomForestClassifier into it.

```
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0,class_weight='auto',min_samples_split=10,n_estimators=50))
clf.fit(train,dv_train)
print clf.feature_importances_
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'OneVsRestClassifier' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_'
```

How can I get the feature importance of each Random Forests in the OneVsRestClassifier?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`OneVsRestClassifier` has an attribute `estimators_` : list of n_classes estimators

So to get the feature importance of the `i`th RandomForest

```
print clf.estimators_[i].feature_importances_
```

Comment: I believe that this is not possible with the new scikit-learn version. Is there some alternative now?