# How to get feature importances of a multi-label classification problem?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, feature-selection, multilabel-classification

I am learning how to use Scikit-Learn and I am trying to get the feature importance of a multi-label classification problem.
I defined and trained the model in the following way:

```
classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(
    make_pipeline(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42))
)
classifier.classes_ = classes
y_train_pred = cross_val_predict(classifier, X_train_prepared, y_train, cv=3)
```

The code seems to be working fine until I try to get the feature importance. This is what I tried:

```
classifier.feature_importances_
```

But I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-98-a9c91f6f2504> in <module>
----> 1 classifier.feature_importances_

AttributeError: 'OneVsRestClassifier' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_'
```

I tried also the solution proposed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137011/getting-random-forest-feature-importances-from-onevsrestclassifier-for-multi-la) but I think it is outdated.
Would you be able to propose a newer smart and elegant solution to display the feature importances of a multi-label classification problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the solution within the referenced post is not outdated; instead, you have a slightly different setting to take care of.

The `estimator` that you're passing to `OneVsRestClassifier` is a `Pipeline`; in the referenced post it was a `RandomForestClassifier` directly.

Therefore you'll have to access one of the pipeline's steps to get to the `RandomForestClassifier` instance on which you'll be finally able to access the `feature_importances_` attribute. That's one way of proceeding:

```
classifier.estimators_[0].named_steps['randomforestclassifier'].feature_importances_
```

Eventually, be aware that you'll have to *fit* your `OneVsRestClassifier` instance to be able to access its `estimators_` attribute. Indeed, though `cross_val_predict` already takes care of fitting the estimator as you might see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09bcc2eaeba98f7e737aac2ac782f0e5f1/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L963), `cross_val_predict` does not return the estimator instance, as `.fit()` method does. Therefore, outside `cross_val_predict` the  fact that `classifier` was fit is not known, reason why you're not able to access the `estimators_` attribute.

Here is a toy example:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, stratify=y, random_state=0)

classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(
    make_pipeline(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42))
)

classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_train_pred = cross_val_predict(classifier, X_train, y_train, cv=3) 
classifier.estimators_[0].named_steps['randomforestclassifier'].feature_importances_
```