# Inspection of the feature importance in scikit-learn pipelines

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

I have defined the following pipelines using scikit-learn:

```
model_lg = Pipeline([("preprocessing", StandardScaler()), ("classifier", LogisticRegression())])
model_dt = Pipeline([("preprocessing", StandardScaler()), ("classifier", DecisionTreeClassifier())])
model_gb = Pipeline([("preprocessing", StandardScaler()), ("classifier", HistGradientBoostingClassifier())])
```

Then I used cross validation to evaluate the performance of each model:

```
cv_results_lg = cross_validate(model_lg, data, target, cv=5, return_train_score=True, return_estimator=True)
cv_results_dt = cross_validate(model_dt, data, target, cv=5, return_train_score=True, return_estimator=True)
cv_results_gb = cross_validate(model_gb, data, target, cv=5, return_train_score=True, return_estimator=True)
```

When I try to inspect the feature importance for each model using the `coef_` method, it gives me an attribution error:

```
model_lg.steps[1][1].coef_
AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'coef_'

model_dt.steps[1][1].coef_
AttributeError: 'DecisionTreeClassifier' object has no attribute 'coef_'

model_gb.steps[1][1].coef_
AttributeError: 'HistGradientBoostingClassifier' object has no attribute 'coef_'
```

I was wondering, how I can fix this error? or is there any other approach to inspect the feature importance in each model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imo, the point here is the following. On the one side, the pipeline instances `model_lg`, `model_dt` etc. are not *explicitely fitted* (you're not calling method `.fit()` on them directly) and this prevents you from trying to access the `coef_` attribute on the instances themselves.

On the other side, by calling `.cross_validate()` with parameter `return_estimator=True` (which is possible with `.cross_validate()` only among the cross-validation methods), you can get the *fitted estimators* back for each cv split, but you should access them via your dictionaries `cv_results_lg`, `cv_results_dt` etc (on the `'estimator'` key). [Here's the reference in the code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/582fa30a31ffd1d2afc6325ec3506418e35b88c2/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L301) and here's an example:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

model_lg = Pipeline([("preprocessing", StandardScaler()), ("classifier", LogisticRegression())])

cv_results_lg = cross_validate(model_lg, X, y, cv=5, return_train_score=True, return_estimator=True)
```

These would be - for instance - the results computed on the first fold.

```
cv_results_lg['estimator'][0].named_steps['classifier'].coef_
```

Useful insights on related topics might be found in:

- [How to get feature importances of a multi-label classification problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71008336/how-to-get-feature-importances-of-a-multi-label-classification-problem/71009063#71009063)
- [Get support and ranking attributes for RFE using Pipeline in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71279499/get-support-and-ranking-attributes-for-rfe-using-pipeline-in-python-3/71280715#71280715)

Answer (score -1):

make for loop in some algorithm and print accuracy